# Finding all items that do not exist in table - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am I having trouble getting my SQL query to return the data that I need. What I am trying to do is get all of the records that are missing out of a table. So if I have records : `92401, 92402, 92404, 92406` I want the query to return `92403, 92405`.

This is the query that I am trying to use right now:

```
select TicketNum
from Tickets
where not exists(select TicketNum
             from TicketBooks
             where TicketBooks.TicketNum=Tickets.TicketNum)
```

Currently this will return no data. If I change the where clause to just `exists` then it will return all of the records that are in the table.

The values `92403, 92405` do not exist in `Tickets`, but they exist in `TicketBooks`.

Any suggestions on how I can modify my query to show such results?

Comment: Do the values `92403, 92405` actually exist in the `Tickets` table and not in the `TicketBooks` one?

Comment: Obviously the table `TicketBooks` contains all  `TicketNum` of the table `Tickets`.

Comment: The values `92403, 92405` does not exist in Tickets, but they do exists in TicketBooks.

Comment: @ChaseErnst Then your query is the other way around. You should be doing `FROM TicketBooks WHERE NOT EXISTS(..... FROM Tickets....)`

Comment: @Lamark add your comment as an answer and I will mark it correct. Thank you!!!

Comment: @ChaseErnst No need to, there's already one answer that says the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The values 92403, 92405 don't exist in Tickets, but they exist
>   in TicketBooks.

So you want to check the opposite:

```
SELECT TicketNum FROM TicketBooks
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Tickets WHERE Tickets.TicketNum = TicketBooks.TicketNum
)
```